# In what year was the conquest of the Incas completed?

Tags: inca, south-america

Following my [other post](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/5637/how-come-incans-believed-that-the-spanish-were-the-incarnation-of-their-thunder) about the Inca and Francisco Pizarro, I would like to know a simple fact: What year was the conquest of the Incas completed?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is general reference

Comment: Unfortunately, there's no general reference close reason here because it's very hard to define.

Comment: @Luke: I edited the question to make it less trivial. In its original form, the question was "basic" and should have been closed. The standard definition (from other SE sites) is that the "question is answerable by a SINGLE link to a web page." And we really should have "basic" as a close reason. But there were two good answers that gave the whole chronology, which might have required SEVERAL references rather than one. That's why I edited the question and suggest that it be left open.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1572, with the capture and execution of [Túpac Amaru](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T%C3%BApac_Amaru), the last Inca monarch.

Túpac Amaru's execution effectively completed the [Spanish conquest of the Inca Empire](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spanish_conquest_of_the_Inca_Empire) that had started 40 years earlier with the [Battle of Cajamarca](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_Cajamarca) (November 16, 1532) and the capture of [Atahualpa](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atahualpa).

Answer (score 4):

Take your pick from the following:

**16 November 1532:** Pizarro captures the Inca Atahulpa at Cajamarca.

**26 July 1533:** Pizarro executes the Inca Atahualpa at Cajamarca.

**15 November 1533:** Pizarro seizes the city of Cuzco.

**July 1537:** Manco Inca abandons his rebellion against the Spaniards and retreats to Vilcabamba.

**September 1572:** The Spaniards execute the last Inca, Tupac Amaru, in Cuzco.

I don't think there's one particular year in which you could say the conquest of the Incas occurred (just as you can't say that the defeat of the Germans in WWI or WWII occurred in one particular year).

I would say that November 1532 (Atahualpa's capture) was the beginning of the end, and that  September 1572 (Tupac Amaru's execution) was the end of the end.

**[www.incahistory.com](http://www.incahistory.com)**